# App is crashing in release mode but working fine in debug mode Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, flutter-dependencies, release, flutter-animation

My app is working fine in debug mode but when I am making a release apk then I am getting this error and my app is crashing just after the apk is installed.

Initially my app was working fine in release mode also but after using the package zego_uikit_prebuilt_video_conference my app is crashing in release mode.

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_object == null F/zygote64(21941): java_vm_ext.cc:534] in call to GetObjectClass F/zygote64(21941): java_vm_ext.cc:534] from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) F/zygote64(21941): java_vm_ext.cc:534] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable flutter..........

I have also made changes in prograd rules:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.KHUSH
    }
}
```

How to remove the error and make the app work fine in release mode?